# The type android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewICS is not visible

Tags: java, android, eclipse, importerror

I am trying to import the following class for an android project
    import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewICS.OnItemClickListener;
But I get an error "The type android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewICS is not visible" All my other imports are working fine thus far and I am using the android ADT bundle downloaded directly from google.

Comment: Why do you think a `android.support.v7.internal` class would be visible? It is marked internal. Try explaining why you need it.

Comment: I want to use the OnItemClickListener class from the support library and in order to do so I have to import it. Am I importing the wrong class? I used Eclipse's auto import feature to import it.

Comment: "I want to use the OnItemClickListener class from the support library" -- why? What do you expect that interface to do that the `OnItemClickListener` interface that is in the standard Android SDK does not do?

Comment: if you want to use android.support.v7 features you should first download v7 supported library after that you have to attach this library to your project

Comment: The Library is downloaded and is in my project. The reason I want to use onItemClickListener is to fix an issue with my app. The app will crash due to not being able to find a function that does exist, however inside a place holder fragment class. Using onItemClick listener was an alternative method of declaring the class so it can be found.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a similar problem after a git merge and, probably, Eclipse being crazy about packages auto-import.

Just replace

```
import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewICS.OnItemClickListener;
```

with

```
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
```

The original AdapterView is supported since [API Level 1](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) thus you will not break the app on old devices.

Answer (score 0):

replace the import statement"import android.support.v7.internal.widget.AdapterViewICS.OnItemClickListener;" with "import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;",sometimes Eclipse cannot find the right packages for auto import.